# What does the one refer to in this paragraph?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have the following paragraph:

> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. **One** shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

I want to know what does the "One" mean. My idea: why it's not "A shape" or "The shape", etc. If you could explain why not for all other choices it will help me a lot!

The paragraph is from a documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape

Comment: [Correction: What does "one" mean? //Why isn't it "A shape" etc. It would help me a lot.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just googled `numpy` so I hope I'm not misreading this! The `shape` describes the dimensions of an array, and `reshape` allows you to change those dimensions by setting new values. So as far as I can tell, it's saying you can pass `-1` for the value of **one** of those dimensions, and it will calculate an appropriate value based on the others. (The last example at the bottom of the page shows this happening.)

So it's not *one shape*, it's *one shape dimension* - *dimension* is the noun, *shape* is acting as an adjective. They're using *one* instead of *a* because you can specifically pass `-1` for **one** dimension, no more! It's more explicit about the number than *a*

Answer (score 0):

It is poorly worded.  They are saying that -1 is a valid input for the "newshape" parameter.